# Weird file/library structuring in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just downloaded android studio (3.4) after formatting my computer and when I launch it, I get this weird project structuring without the ordinary manifest, resources, java folders etc.
also I have no "Create a new activity" option or pretty much any of the android or java options under File > New. Neither is there an android option under tools
stack overflow wouldn't allow me to post images so here:

[image]

[image]

I have tried marking the src directory as Sources Root but when I do that "android" becomes an unresolved symbol

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @a_local_nobody Pretty sure that's what it is.

Comment: Do you have the Android SDK installed?

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException pretty sure that installs with android studio, if not where can i install it.

Comment: @a_local_nobody do you mean File > New > Project then choose empty activity java etc.. Yep I did so a couple of times actually

Comment: @a_local_nobody believe it or not, I did that like 3 times, Uninstalled all the sdks, projects, jdk, android directory etc. at this point the only option left is to burn my pc

Comment: Right. Your JDK might not be configured. Also check if the sdk and jdk is valid

Comment: @PixiPro You could install the command line tools from the site. Extract it into a folder named "sdk" and point Android Studio to it.

Comment: @a_local_nobody I really think the problem is with android rather than java. anw I tried that and it didn't work :/

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException extracting command line tools seemed to work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks to @a_local_nobody too, i'll be waiting for my 5 bucks :D

Comment: i have no idea what you're talking about ?? :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a bad Android SDK - to get a new one, got to this [site](https://developer.android.com/studio), scroll down until you see the command line tools. Download the correct .zip file and extract to a new folder (name it androidsdk or something) and point Android Studio to your new SDK (androidsdk). Android Studio will automatically configure and download all the packages needed to make your new SDK usable.